# Initialize a DbSet without a Context in C# - Mocking

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, iqueryable, xunit.net, dbset

I'm writing a Test Cases for a Common generic methods, In that I don't have any database configuration, but the method generic method is handling the IQueryable object. So, I tried the following code

```
public static DbSet<Person> GetPersonDbSet() {
    DbSet<Person> record = null;
    record.Add(new Person() {
        PersonId = 1,
        FirstName = "Ram",
        LastName = "Kumar"
    });

    record.Add(new Person() {
        PersonId = 2,
        FirstName = "Raj",
        LastName = "Kumar"
    });

    return record;
}
```

Original Method:

```
public static class MyLib {
    public static IQueryable Pagination<T>(IOrderedQueryable<T> query, int offset, int limit) {

        // Validation Code (...)

        // Main Logic
        return query.Skip(offset).Take(limit);

    }
}
```

Test Method:

```
[Fact]
public void CheckPagination() {
    var query = GetPersonDbSet().OrderBy(i => i.FirstName);

    var result = MyLib.Pagination(query, 1, 5);
    int count = result.Count();
    Assert.True(count > 0);
}
```

I got an exception in `GetPersonDbSet()` while on adding the entity, because the variable `DbSet<Person> record` was initialized with `null`. Kindly assist me how to Initialize and achieve this without a context (because in this project I'm not using any Database Context).

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with:

`DbSet<Person> record = new TestDbSet<Person>();`

and have a read of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314431(v=vs.113).aspx (which includes the definition of TestDbSet).